# Unix-How to Grep inside PKZIP files?

Tags: grep, zip

I would like to do a grep inside my zip file.

While i was trying with zgrep it doesn't work because when I tried with command
File

It returns the file as PKZIP: compressed archive

Zgrep doesn't work under pkzip files it seems.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

One (heavy) method, if you have multiple grep to do, is to mount your zip with [fuse-zip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fuse-zip.1.html) and grep files in the mounted directory.